# Where are the files for the language indicator in Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS stored?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, indicator, time

Recently while I was working on the command line directly after booting I noticed that the *language / keyboard layout* has been changed. Instead of restarting `lightdm` I just rebooted and nothing has changed. After all, I saw the little icon of the language indicator on the top right side was set to another language.
Of course I changed the language back to my favored one.

But now I want to know, which files I have to look for, where these info's are stored. Especially I want to trace back this changes.

This is the timestamp of my keyboard settings.

```
$ ls --full-time /etc/default/keyboard
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 150 2019-05-28 14:43:36.298775034 +0200 /etc/default/keyboard
```

But the changes appeard on june the 27th.

Any hint is appreceated.

Answer (score 1):

The input sources which LightDM make available on the login screen are taken both from `/etc/default/keyboard` and from the sources which the users on the system have activated.

The user data is taken from the files in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users` (don't edit those files manually unless you know what you are doing).

So the explanation can simply be that yourself or some other user on the system has changed the user level input sources somehow.

Comment: Yes, of course, there must be a reason how the language changed. But how could I trace this? `$ ls --full-time /var/lib/AccountsService/users
insgesamt 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 362 2018-10-27 17:10:27.082141274 +0200 goofy` doesn't give me a further hint. 

If you are talking about _user level input sources_, do you mean the section about `[InputSource0]
xkb=de

[InputSource1]
xkb=us`
 in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users`? If so, I do not understand why `[InputSource1]` is used for decryption before log in and `[InputSource0]` for `lightdm` log in screen.

Comment: @JohnGoofy: If I remember correctly, by default LightDM shows the current source for the selected user on the login screen. So if the current source for user X is "de" after login, you'll see that on the login screen too when user X is selected. (I don't know about decryption, but it might take the layout from `/etc/default/keyboard`.)